# Use image as thumbnails without save its

Tags: asp.net, image, webforms

I want to genrate a thumbnails of image without save its differentlty

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) supports resizing images and it can output the thumbnail to a stream (for example a **MemoryStream**), so you don't have to save the image on disk. It has a very good support for ASP.NET and it can be installed using NuGet.